# PHP Authentication with AD

Tags: php, active-directory

The company I work for has a PHP form that is used by employees. Employees submit tickets through this form but it does not have authentication so we don't actually know who really submits the ticket. The company uses AD Azure to maintain employee profiles. What would be the easiest solution to set up the authentication? Actually the main goal is to know who submitted the ticket so logging in before accessing the form is not recuired.

Thank you

Comment: Is the PHP page hosted in IIS?

Comment: No, it is using Apache

Comment: If you AD support OAuth - this is the easiest way to implement.